# Mercury , Unresolved .orig files after hg revert

Tags: mercurial

After reverting all files , it seems .orig files are created for each files ( on hg status ), how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `hg revert -C` to revert all the files without generating any `.orig` files.

Answer (score 0):

The .orig files are created when mercurial has to do some merges (including automatic ones when updating from a dirty working dir to another revision). If your commits are fine, you are not in the middle of a merge, have no uncommitted changes, then simply delete those.

My .hgignore contains the file extensions .orig, .rej